# How to copy and paste all data from one database to another in jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have two tables, `tableone` and `tabletwo` from a MySQL database. Both tables have the same fields, I want to make one script in jsp that copies all data from `tableone` into `tabletwo`. I have two sql files that contain databases, `tableone.sql` and `tabletwo.sql`.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: It's not different from how you do it in Java. Writing Java code in JSP files instead of normal Java classes doesn't make it a JSP specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this in a JSP. DO this in a Servlet. JSP is used to output HTML markup. Servlets are used to contain Java code executing some logic. Read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

You need to

- create and start a MySQL database. An SQL file doesn't contain a database. It contains SQL instructions that can be used to populate some database.
- create the schema for your two tables (probably with your SQL files, but I don't know what they contain
- learn [how to use JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)
- execute a query which reads every row from table A and insert the data of each row into table B. You'll neeed prepared statements to do that.